# Format a number as a string

Tags: python, string, integer, format

How do you format a number as a string so that it takes a number of spaces in front of it?  I want the shorter number 5 to have enough spaces in front of it so that the spaces plus the 5 have the same length as 52500.  The procedure below works, but is there a built in way to do this?

```
a = str(52500)
b = str(5)
lengthDiff = len(a) - len(b)
formatted = '%s/%s' % (' '*lengthDiff + b, a)
# formatted looks like:'     5/52500'
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Format operator](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting):

```
>>> "%10d" % 5
'         5'
>>>
```

Using `*` spec, the field length can be an argument:

```
>>> "%*d" % (10,5)
'         5'
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just use the `%*d` formatter to give a width. `int(math.ceil(math.log(x, 10)))` will give you the number of digits. The `*` modifier consumes a number, that number is an integer that means how many spaces to space by. So by doing `'%*d'` % (width, num)` you can specify the width AND render the number without any further python string manipulation.

Here is a solution using math.log to ascertain the length of the 'outof' number.

```
import math
num = 5
outof = 52500
formatted = '%*d/%d' % (int(math.ceil(math.log(outof, 10))), num, outof)
```

Another solution involves casting the outof number as a string and using len(), you can do that if you prefer:

```
num = 5
outof = 52500
formatted = '%*d/%d' % (len(str(outof)), num, outof)
```

Comment: len(str(x)) is about twice as fast on my system. It's easier to read too :-)

Comment: Yes but that's assuming you know which side of the equation is the longer one.

Comment: math.ceil(math.log(x, 10)) gives wrong results for powers of 10.

Comment: Ah interesting. that's why you shouldn't test on a single value, and test on edge cases.

Answer (score 2):

'%*s/%s' % (len(str(a)), b, a)

Answer (score 1):

See [String Formatting Operations](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations):

```
s = '%5i' % (5,)
```

You still have to dynamically build your formatting string by including the maximum length:

```
fmt = '%%%ii' % (len('52500'),)
s = fmt % (5,)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you're after, but this looks close:

```
>>> n = 50
>>> print "%5d" % n
   50
```

If you want to be more dynamic, use something like `rjust`:

```
>>> big_number = 52500
>>> n = 50
>>> print ("%d" % n).rjust(len(str(52500)))
   50
```

Or even:

```
>>> n = 50
>>> width = str(len(str(52500)))
>>> ('%' + width + 'd') % n
'   50'
```